# Phrasequery to make researches

Tags: python, lucene

Is there anyway to use phrasequery with python?
until now i was using parser, but i would like to know how to use phrasequery.

```
parser = QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, "contents",
                        analyzer)
parser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.AND)
query = parser.parse(command)
    scoreDocs = searcher.search(query, 10000).scoreDocs
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should understand that when you cut out the QueryParser, you lose the analyzer.  `PhraseQuery` won't analyze for you, like the QueryParser does, so it's on you to tokenize and normalize your phrase to match the index-time analysis.  You may be better off sticking with the parser.

That said, constructing a PhraseQuery manually looks something like this:

```
query = PhraseQuery()
query.add(Term("contents", "lorem"))
query.add(Term("contents", "ipsum"))
query.add(Term("contents", "sit"))
query.add(Term("contents", "amet"))
```

You can set the slop for the query using `setSlop`.

You can also specify the position of each term.  For instance, if "sit" were a stopword in my index, I might do something like:

```
query = PhraseQuery()
query.add(Term("contents", "lorem"), 0)
query.add(Term("contents", "ipsum"), 1)
query.add(Term("contents", "amet"), 3)
```

Comment: but if i need to search for 4grams, i need to do this each time? Excuse me, i am a newbee..

Comment: ngrams generally work by overlapping multiple tokens at the same position.  You should be able to, either, search for one gram at each position, or search for multiples at the same position by specifying them, as in my second code sample.